# How to call an API but only grab one specific piece of info in Python

Tags: python

I want to create a simple python program that calls the [colornames.org](http://colornames.org) API for the name of any given hex code inputted by the user. However, all I want my program to output is the "name" info.

*How can I make it only output that and not all of the information?*

Code below:

```
import requests
import json 

hexcodeinput = input("Hex code you've found (format: FF0000, no #): ")

print(hexcodeinput + " is your selected hex code. Searching...")

response = requests.get("https://colornames.org/search/json/?hex=" + (hexcodeinput))

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the response as json, not as plain text. Then it is a dict which you can use:

```
import requests

hex_code = input("Hex code you've found (format: FF0000, no #): ")

print("%s is your selected hex code. Searching..." % hex_code)

response = requests.get("https://colornames.org/search/json/?hex="+hex_code)
details = response.json()  # a dict with all the info
print(details['name'])  # get the name from that dict
```